# How to use nextLine for scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I used correct data type but I cant find my errors. Below is my code;

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    //Read 
    System.out.printf ("Enter the station: ");
    String s  = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.printf ("Enter quantity in liter: ");
    double q  = input.nextDouble();

    
    System.out.printf ("Enter type of petrol: ");
    String t  = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.printf ("Enter price of petrol: ");
    double p  = input.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.printf ("Enter discount: ");
    int d  = input.nextInt();
```

when I run my program, It does not go to next line to input values. For petrol type, I want to input something like "Super 99" so I need to use input.nextLine() but its not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/*
*****This will work for you dear
*/

import java.util.*;
class Tester
{

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.printf ("Enter the station: ");
    String s  = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.printf ("Enter quantity in liter: ");
    double q  = input.nextDouble();

    input.nextLine();
    System.out.printf ("Enter type of petrol: ");
    String t  = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.printf ("Enter price of petrol: ");
    double p  = input.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.printf ("Enter discount: ");
    int d  = input.nextInt();
   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks alot! it worked and now my program goes to next line and I can input value for both.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

**Use another input.nextLine() right after the   double q  = input.nextDouble(); line.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Read
        System.out.printf ("Enter the station: ");
        String s  = input.nextLine();

        System.out.printf ("Enter quantity in liter: ");
        double q  = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.printf ("Enter type of petrol: ");
        String t  = input.nextLine();

        System.out.printf ("Enter price of petrol: ");
        double p  = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf ("Enter discount: ");
        int d  = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: This breaks if the user enters tokens by space separating. Scanner's useDelimiter method is what you really want. (update the delimiter to be 'newline' instead of 'whitespace').

Comment: @Hasindu Dahanayake yess it worked by adding input.nextLine(). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help you.@ChanMyaeTun

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use:

```
System.out.println("Enter the type of petrol");
```

It will work like this :

```
Enter the type of petrol
Super99     //its what you will enter as per your choice here the cursor will automatically take you to the next line
```

Answer (score -1):

To print a line *including* a newline:

```
System.out.println("Enter price of petrol: ");
// -OR-
System.out.printf("Enter price of petrol: \n");
```

To obtain a single token (a single word, number, integer, etc):

```
scanner.nextInt(); // integer
scanner.next(); // word
```

To obtain an entire line:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");
// now the scanner is in 'entire line' mode
scanner.nextInt(); // still works
scanner.next(); // gets one line's worth
```

To go back to 'one token per whitespace' mode, where entering e.g. "a b c" (enter) will cause 3 `.next()` calls of data to be available:

```
scanner.reset();
// -OR-
scanner.useDelimiter("\s+");
```

TIP: Don't mix `nextLine()` and any other `next` method.

Comment: `System.out.printf("Enter price of petrol: \n");` went to next line but can make input value for both. I have never used scanner.useDelimiter before but I will test it out. Thanks a lot for detailed explanation :)